Is there an alternative solution GraphQL resolveType for union types?
I want to return different field data types (for byte field string or array) through a single query on Graphql.
However,
'Abstract type "GetRecordsWrapper" must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field "Query.records". Either the "GetRecordsWrapper" type should provide a "resolveType" function or each possible type should provide an "isTypeOf" function.'

I get the error. To solve the problem, I added the __resolveType function to the Resolver class, but the same error still persists.
Records Resolver:
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Args, Subscription } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { RecordsService } from './records.service';

import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';
import { CreateRecordInput, UpdateRecordInput} from '../graphql';

const pubSub = new PubSub();


@Resolver('Record')
export class RecordsResolver {
  constructor(private readonly recordsService: RecordsService) {}

  __resolveType(obj: any) {
    if (typeof obj.byte === 'string') {
      return 'HexByteStringResponse';
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj.byte)) {
      return 'ByteArrayResponse';
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Query('records')
  async records(@Args('format') args: "byte" | "array"): Promise<any> {
    return this.recordsService.findAll(args);
  }

Records Service:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Record } from '@prisma/client';

import { PrismaService } from '../prisma/prisma.service';
import { CreateRecordInput, UpdateRecordInput, GetRecordsWrapper, HexByteStringResponse, ByteArrayResponse } from 'src/graphql';


@Injectable()
export class RecordsService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async findAll(format: "byte" | "array"): Promise<GetRecordsWrapper[]> {
    const records = await this.prisma.record.findMany({
      include: {
        provider: true,
      },
    });
  
    return records.map(record => {
      if (format === "byte") {
        return {
          ...record,
          byte: `0x${record.byte.toString('hex')}`,
        } as HexByteStringResponse;
      } else {
        return {
          ...record,
          byte: Array.from(record.byte),
        } as ByteArrayResponse;
      }
    });
  }

Graphql Schema includes Union:
scalar DateTime
scalar Bytes
scalar Provider

type Record {
  id: ID!
  byte: Bytes!
  sendedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  provider: Provider!
}

type HexByteStringResponse {
  id: ID!
  byte: String!
  sendedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  provider: Provider!
}

type ByteArrayResponse {
  id: ID!
  byte: [Int!]!
  sendedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  provider: Provider!
}

union GetRecordsWrapper = HexByteStringResponse | ByteArrayResponse

type Query {
  records(format: String!): [GetRecordsWrapper]!
  record(id: String!): GetRecordsWrapper
  recordsWrapper(type: String!): GetRecordsWrapper
}


What is Record in your schema? It doesn't appear to be used anywhere.

Having a format argument and returning a union of types that differ in only one field is a weird way to model this. The schema doesn't guarantee that records returns a homogeneous array, nor that it returns responses that match the passed format. Really you should have only a single type Record { bytes: Bytes!; bytesAsArray: [Int]!; bytesAsHex: String!; … }, so that the client can choose which field to query based on what format they want.

Record is a type model that defines the model in the database, I used Record only for create. I use ByteArrayResponse and HexByteStringResponse types for get.

You'd need to put __resolveType on the resolvers of GetRecordsWrapper , not on those of the unrelated Record. Or maybe the whole class should be @Resolver('GetRecordsWrapper') export class GetRecordsWrapperService { … instead of @Resolver('Record') export class RecordsService { …, given its method that implements Query.records despite not returning any Records?
However, there's a simpler solution than providing a __resolveType method on the union type. You can just return each object with a __typename property, and the default __resolveType implementation will use that.
return records.map(format === "byte"
  ? (record): HexByteStringResponse => ({
    ...record,
    __typename: 'HexByteStringResponse',
    byte: `0x${record.byte.toString('hex')}`,
  })
  : (record): ByteArrayResponse => ({
    ...record,
    __typename: 'ByteArrayResponse',
    byte: Array.from(record.byte),
  })
);


Yes, you are right, after specifying __typename, I do not need to override __resolveType.

I think you should write resolver for the union, not for the record itself.
As per docs here
@Resolver('GetRecordsWrapper')
export class GetRecordsWrapperResolver {
  __resolveType(obj: any) {
    if (typeof obj.byte === 'string') {
      return 'HexByteStringResponse';
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj.byte)) {
      return 'ByteArrayResponse';
    }
    return null;
  }

}

Yes, i tried this too by writing it to a separate tsx file and then importing it into the module, but it didn't work.
